# PyGTK connect_signals

Tags: python, pygtk

Ok so I have a little test program here:

This is in my file that I load through gtk.Builder

```
<object class="GtkWindow" id="mainWindow">
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">250</property>
    <signal name="delete_event" handler="endProgram" />
</object>
```

I then use this:

```
def endProgram ():
    print "end";

rofl = gtk.Builder();

rofl.add_from_file("mainwindow.ui");
win = rofl.get_object("mainWindow");
rofl.connect_signals("mainWindow");
win.show_all();
gtk.main();
```

Yet when I go to run that it complains that I am missing a handler for the mainWindow object.
I have tried doing     rofl.connect_signals(win); as well

Answer (score 3):

Per [the docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbuilder.html#method-gtkbuilder--connect-signals), `connect_signals` takes as the argument a mapping or instance, and

> uses Python's introspective features
>   to look at the keys (if object is a
>   mapping) or attributes (if object is
>   an instance) and tries to match them
>   with the signal handler names given in
>   the interface description. The
>   callbacks referenced by each matched
>   key or attribute are connected to
>   their matching signals.

So for example when you pass `"mainwindow"`, which is an instance of `str`, the attributes are e.g. such method names as `upper`, `lower`, `isalpha`, and the like -- nothing to do with anything at all that you might be remotely interested about.  And why would you want the attributes of `win` to handle signals, either?  IOW, what do you expect `connect_signals` to **do**?

A more typical example use can be found e.g. in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129369/gtk-builder-and-multiple-glade-files-breaks) and [this tutorial](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-3.html), which offers among others the following Python example:

```
class TutorialTextEditor:

    def on_window_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):

        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("tutorial.xml") 

        self.window = builder.get_object("window")
        builder.connect_signals(self)
```

as you see, here `connect_signals` is used in the typical way -- i.e., passing an object (`self`) with an `on_window_destroy` method that (by introspection) will be used as the handler for the signal raised on window destruction.

Comment: Another approach is to pass a dict: builder.connect_signals(dict(signal_name=handler))